# Can we please be given the option to opt-out of collectives' weekly leaderboard notifications?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, notifications, collectives

Being part of the [Intel Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel?tab=members) on Stack Overflow, and answering questions on the [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86) tag, from time to time I get reminded that I am "in the Top X contributors for the Intel Collective":

[image: screenshot of the notification]

I honestly do not care *that much* about the leaderboard to feel the need of being notified when I am Top 15 on the weekly one. What's this, a race? It's also nothing exceptional as [you currently only need *one upvote*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IEPU.png) on any Q/A on any of the Intel collective tags to be in the Top 15, so this is like "congrats, you got an upvote".

I would understand being notified of being in the Top **3** on the weekly leaderboard *in the achievements tab*, as that'd also mean receiving a shiny gold/silver/bronze trophy case near my name shown everywhere on the site on my user card, though I still wouldn't find that of much use since I'd notice it on any page.

When I look at the inbox icon and I see a "1" in a red circle I associate that with me receiving some reply, comment, Chat mention, or in general something needing my attention. Being in the Top X on a weekly imaginary points leaderboard of some kind does not really need my attention, so I think receiving an inbox notification for it is unnecessary/inappropriate.

---

Could such a notification be shown after a higher threshold in the achievements tab instead, in the same way as when you receive a new badge (green-lit reputation icon), being a reputation-related "achievement"? Or better, could we just be given the option to opt-out of such kind of notifications, much like we are given [the option to opt-out of collective invitations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJlY0.jpg)?

Comment: IMHO it doesn't really belong in the rep tab (actually called "achievements"). The achievements are a timeline of events, whereas being in the Collective top-N is a transient state. It really is just a notification. It should be made less easy to attain, like top-3, which is accompanied by the trophy icon, or at least opt-out. But I guess their goal is to maximize engagement.

Comment: As a work-around, you can try to permanently stay in the top-15, no more notifications then :)

Comment: As a better work-around, you can just leave the collective. It’s not like you get any benefits from being there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The near-term change will be to only notify the members in the top three leaderboard positions. We do have some plans for other visual indicators to note ranking changes. We will be thinking about the management and location of these notifications as Collectives evolves.

Comment: Just checking in because I still seem to keep getting these "Top 15" notifications. Is there an estimate of when this near-term change you mention will get in place?

Comment: 2+ months now. What does near-term mean? One quarter? One year? 6 to 8 weeks?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I am pleased to report this is being worked on right now! We'll note here when the change is released. It's tough to estimate time-until-release when a request first gets put in, since it's evaluated based on relative priority to everything else on an ongoing basis. In this case, "near-term" was meant to communicate that there might be a different solution further down the road.

Comment: This change has been made; only the top three leaderboard positions will receive the notifications.

Comment: *"In this case, "near-term" was meant to communicate that there might be a different solution further down the road"* - ah, gotcha! Thanks for the replies.